# What sequence are stock units held by us sold in?

Tags: stocks, india, trading, capital-gains-tax

This is specific to Indian Stock Market but I'd like to know about other markets as well if it works differently there.

Here's the scenario:-

I bought 10 units for INR 10 each.

The stock went up by 10, now each of my purchased unit is worth INR 20 each.

I bought another 10 units at INR 20 each.

After this, the stock went down by 5, so I sold 12 units, now I have 8 remaining.

Question: How many units did I sell of which purchase price? Is it 10 of the ones bought at INR 10 and 2 of the ones bought at INR 20 (Account Balance **+40**) or is it the other way around (Account Balance **-40**)? Just to confirm, what happens if I had another set of 10 that were purchased at INR 5?

Please let me know if this is a dumb question and I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on *which* ones you sold, and there are names for the choices:

- FIFO: first-in-first-out, meaning you sold the oldest ones first,
- LIFO: last-in-first-out, meaning you sold the newest ones first,
- Weighted Average: meaning you sold a (theoretical perfect) mixture of all you had,
- Selected Lots: meaning you explicitly specify which shares you sell, mixed as you like from any lot.

I cannot tell you what *your* provider uses as default, but usually, you can set either one as your *default*, and you can additionally change the applied procedure *after* each sale, but only until it is settled.
If you don't ever set or change anything, most providers will use FIFO - but again, yours might have another default.